# Integration of android apps

Tags: android

I am new to Android. I want to know is there any solution for integrate android apps into our project. Like we can use Analytics code in web popups of a website. How can we know the installed device ids of that particular application?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate apps but only those who like you to integrate i.e., like facebook login can be integrated in your app because api is available to you.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

like this you can integrate any app by using their api.

Comment: Ok @prashant thanks for reply. By using Intent can i send data like my project number and my customer's registrationId to any perticular servlet?

Comment: Through Intent You can only send information to other app, like you have integrated whatsapp in your app, then you can easily intent any msg to whatsapp and it'll ask user to send it, then it will be through whatsapp servers.
If you want to send any data to a perticular servlet then you will use http object